Does Jesus get a special pass for calling Herod a fox?
Jesus taught that every careless word shall be required of us in the day of judgment.
Mathew 12:36-37

But I tell you that men will have to give account on the day of judgment for every careless word they have spoken

Personally, I do believe that calling any human being made in the image of God a fox to be a sin because all men are made in the image of God. Jesus did refer to Herod as a fox.
Luke 13:32

Go tell that fox, 'Look, I will keep driving out demons and healing people today and tomorrow, and on the third day I will reach My goa

Does Jesus get a special pass for this? because any Christian would be sinning in calling anyone a fox

Jesus also said: “be wise as serpents and innocent as doves”.  So, to earn the nickname “fox” one would have to excel in craftiness. Thus, to call Herod a fox was just a recognition of his wisdom in executing his office.

@Constantthin, is there any hermeneutic evidence to support the claim that Herod was as cunning as a fox?

The question carries with it the assumption that Jesus is sinning somehow by calling Herod a fox.  While there is a lively discussion as to what is meant by fox (whether it is a reference to Herod's sneakiness or not), the discussion doesn't change the fact that the metaphor fits.  Jesus was simply "speaking the truth in love." (eph 4.).
Calling Herod a fox was not nearly as 'spicy' as Jesus speaks elsewhere. If Jesus is sinning by calling Herod a fox, what do you do with his language to the Pharisees?:  ““Woe to you, teachers of the law and Pharisees, you hypocrites! You travel over land and sea to win a single convert, and when you have succeeded, you make them twice as much a child of hell as you are.” (Matthew 23:15 NIV11-GKE).
Calling someone a "son of hell" (υἱὸν γεέννης) is even stronger than calling someone a 'fox.'
So, in essence, it would be good to prove your premise that Jesus is "speaking a careless word."  I don't see any evidence.  The biblical criteria are met: He speaks the truth in love.  He doesn't always tell people what they want to hear.
Furthermore, it would be good to provide some evidence that Christians calling others, "foxes" would be a sin.  In the biblical context, on the one hand, speaking in such a way as to tear down a person's reputation (breaking the 8th commandment) is forbidden. But, on the other hand, speaking in such a way so as to both speak the truth and show true Christian love for the other person means that, yes, in fact, we will have to use language that the other person may not be comfortable with.
So Jesus doesn't need a "pass", since he isn't doing anything that is wrong.

What is the difference between these two statements, go tell that fox and go tell that dog?

Calling someone a fox is a sin because all men are made in the image of God , a fox is not made in the image of God


Jesus is using a metaphor. He isn't directly calling Herod a fox as if he had pointy ears and a tail. There is no reference to the image of God in this verse at all.


Jesus also called the Pharisees and Sadducees coming for baptism "You brood of vipers" in Matthew 3:7. Does Jesus actually have the right to judge people? Apparently, he sorta DOES get a special pass as a member of the Godhead.

God made everything. Foxes, sheep, goats, vultures, and dogs. Adam gave them names. We may view Foxes as sly and careful, but they have broods, care for, and raise their young. So somehow (I may be wrong, but) , I think His image is in them too (just as my image is in the things I do). Man has the choice to choose good or evil.

There are layered assumptions. I'm not saying they're false but it's as well to unpack them.
==
1. That Jesus will be judged as a man
Mt12:36 ...ἀποδώσουσιν περὶ αὐτοῦ λόγον...
If Jesus is the Logos, that's pointed phrasing.
But the passage doesn't give any indication if Jesus will be judged as a man. Elsewhere there is him judging e.g. Matthew 25:31 (the son of man separating the sheep from the goats) but nothing to clarify that Heaven is a rule-of-law jurisdiction.
==
2. That to call Herod a fox meets the definition of careless words.
Mt12:36 - λαλήσουσιν tends to be chatter or chit-chat or prattle or babble (Liddell & Scott). Or more archaically Aristophanes used it for "gossip". We have some colourful colloquial terms now, like "diss" and "talk smack about" and it could be within those. But what it doesn't carry is "careless" as a distinct idea. It's onomatopoeic with the reduplicated L sound representing a speaker in a repetitive/mindless tone. The many translations with variations on "careless" probably get that from KJV, who get "idle" from the lazy internal mindset more than the sound or motion of the speech.
εἴπατε τῇ ἀλώπεκι (tell that fox) might be too brief and too contained to qualify as λαλεῖν.
But that's a technical line of defence and the counsel for the prosecution might be able to construct something from Exodus or Leviticus. It's not bearing-false-witness if it's just to Luke... but maybe it betrays covetousness of Herod's status.
If it's open to make a contention of the OP's form, there are more implications that come in on its coat-tails.
Also the OP's contention brings together two out-of-context quotes. Taking Mt12:36 in context Jesus has just qualified what he means by λαλεῖν, which is the Pharisees' accusal at Mt.12:24
"But when the Pharisees heard it, they said, “It is only by Beelzebul, the prince of demons, that this man casts out demons."
This is far graver than calling someone a fox - it is false witness in the sense of the commandment in Exodus, and they've accused Jesus of a crime that carried the death penalty, which we know they do carry through. So it's the worst possible sort of false witness. λαλεῖν is dramatically understating it.
==
3. That Jesus wouldn't give a satisfactory account (Matthew 12:37 - δικαιωθήσῃ by your words you will be justified or condemned)
Mt.12:36 implies a court-trial with the obligation (but also the opportunity) for those tried to defend themselves.
Virtually any adjective could fairly be applied to a mass-murderer of infants (Matthew 2:16-18).
The Logos might be uniquely difficult to convict of slander, if the truth is what it says it is. (Psalm 33:9 - For He spoke, and it came to be; He commanded, and it stood firm. Or Isaiah 23:1 - Tyre is laid waste [...] the word has come to her.)
On a juristic or atheist-humanist treatment of the passage, I contend this becomes stronger not weaker. If an question is raised in terms of sin, regarding a passage in the gospel, but is non-theistic - it's incumbent first to clarify what's understood by sin. It must explain why Jesus is subject to judgement without enjoying any rights to free speech. Or if Jesus isn't divine isn't there a prior question whether he gets a vote, before we worry about whether he gets a "pass"?
We can't say for sure if there were any local/contemporary laws against calling Herod names. All we know from the text is that wasn't among the eventual charges.
Matthew sometimes offers readers familiar non-theistic conceptual apparatus - e.g. Judas acknowledging Jesus' blood is innocent (Matthew 27:4). But not here - there isn't a disapproving adverb on εἶπεν , or a reaction from the interlocutors.
==
4. That if he was found guilty, Jesus wouldn't be forgiven on existing precedent (such that it's to be a "special" pass)
e.g. on the basis of the preceding passage "every sin and blasphemy can be forgiven" (Matthew 12:31)
[humour] It's amusing to wonder how God's Judgement might handle conflicts-of-interest. The OP's contention involves admitting heavenly judgement as a premise. There are theologies in which Jesus is a creature, but even his being  a... hmm... prominent character in the deity's advertising collateral. is enough to present a conflict-of-interest. I wonder if there's a Duns Scotus type argument that for Heaven to have put Jesus in that position, it would have been good of them to have given him a pass, and therefore Heaven did give him a pass. [/humour]
==
5. The law-sin-judgement parallels hold up in this situation
Lastly a point of housekeeping - the Matthew passage emphasizes the Judgement, and the OP's contention is somewhat juristic or letter-of-the-law. The Luke passage (as already noted) doesn't directly confirm or surely support the inference that calling Herod a fox was sin. But if God's jurisdiction is anything like his monetary economics (e.g. in the parable of the workers in the vineyard Matthew 20:1-16) there's no reason to suppose we know how an ἀπολόγιον and κρίσις of Jesus would resemble an earthly court.
When God's judgement is applied back to God, sometimes in search of a (being charitable) productive recursion, it can be a lead-in for the traditional questions of Christology. Must the human nature be judged? Does the divine nature judge the human nature? But I submit neither these passages, nor the combination of them, nor the questions they present give new entries to that.

its because Jesus said whosever says to his own brother raca is risking being condemned to hell

@SoFewAgainstSoMany that would be from Mt.5:22 but if I started answering questions that aren't in the question I'd be off-topic. I take raca(=emptyhead/numbskull) to be consistent with the 2 examples in these passages of understatement as a mannerism of Jesus (although some might be more comfortable attributing it to a whole-culture mode of hyperbole). This isn't importantly different from the passage the OP did bring, in terms of its interaction with Luke 13:32. It's helpful if we're not sure what court, but I think we're sure. But if I've missed your point it's open to you to show why.

For reference, here is one of several questions about what Jesus meant when he called Herod (Antipas) a "fox." But whether he meant it as an insult or not, he does not need a "special pass" for saying it.
The question might be more difficult if Jesus had said something like this publicly or to Herod's face. Here, however, it was a private conversation with several Pharisees who warned him to flee because Herod wanted to kill him. This is a rare instance where the NT reports cooperation between Pharisees and Jesus, and Jesus naturally used language that made common cause with them.
In fact, Jesus often used language that could be considered insulting. He called his opponents "fools" and "blind guides" (Matthew 23:16-17) even though he strictly told his disciples to call no one "fool." (Matthew 5:22)  He even called his own chief disciple "Satan." (Mark 8:33)
It is true, as the OP points out, that Jesus said everyone will face judgment for careless words. Whether Jesus is exempt from judgment is a matter of theological opinion. However it is hard to think that God would damn someone - whether Jesus or anyone else - for speaking carelessly on occasion. Jesus taught that we should avoid this, but the threat of judgment for a careless word should be considered hyperbole.

When he ordered the disciples to be wise as serpents and innocent as doves, that is not as  direct as this incident wher he called Herod a fox

I think it was an intentional word, not a careless one!

The decisive question should be whether Herod deserved to be called a fox, a metaphor for stealth, and not why Jesus called him as such. Mtt 2:3 says that the whole of Jerusalem with Herod ( father of Antipas )got troubled at the birth of Jesus. And we see Jesus lamenting over the impending fate of Jerusalem immediately after speaking of Herod  (Lk 13:34). Fast-forward to the trial of Jesus, we see him being presented before Herod, but the latter recuses  himself from judging Jesus. Luke 23:12 says that Herod and Pilate who had  hitherto been  enemies, became friends after the conviction of Jesus. What does it all say ? Herod in fact,wanted in kill Jesus but when the opportunity came, he passed the buck on to Pilate. Admittedly, there was a tacit understanding between Herod and Pilate. Courtesy Wikipedia, let us have a summary of the ' drama ' that is was :
While questioning Jesus about the claim of being the King of the Jews, Pilate realizes that Jesus is a Galilean and therefore under Herod's jurisdiction. Since Herod already happened to be in Jerusalem at that time, Pilate decides to send Jesus to Herod to be tried.
Herod Antipas (not to be confused with Herod Antipas's father, Herod the Great who was alleged to have ordered the Massacre of the innocents)is the same man who had previously ordered the death of John the Baptist and, according to some Pharisees,had plotted to have Jesus killed as well, but had wanted to see Jesus for a long time, hoping to observe one of the miracles of Jesus. However, Jesus says nothing in response to Herod's questions, or the vehement accusations of the chief priests and the scribes.
Soldiers put a gorgeous robe on Jesus, mocking him as King of the Jews, and send him back to Pilate. That day, Herod and Pilate, who had previously been enemies, become friends.
<  In the case of John the Baptist too,  one can make out the hidden agenda of Herod executed to look like it all happened per chance : daughter of his ' wife' being asked to dance at the party; Herod promising her the earth--knowing too well that the girl would definitely consult her mother to whom the Baptist was the sworn enemy, and then Herod obliging  the cruel wish of his illegitimate wife.
< Of course, the Lord was aware of what was to happen to him at the hands of the crafty rulers. But what pained him more was  the mindset of the people of Jerusalem, whom he sympathises with. As for Herod ,the Lord aptly calls him a man of stealth , and openly challenges him to lay hands on the Son of God. Sure, God the Father was  not going to ask  him " Son, don't you feel you went a bit too far in labelling  Herod a fox  ? " . After all, who else knew Herod best  ?

So the fox phrase is simply a metaphor for he behavior of Herod who also murdered one of his own sons?

Beyond that, rather. You can call it a quintessential statement about his life and character.
